# How to check if an element contain more than 3 characters

Tags: python

Hello I have several string such as:

```
>>> for leaf in tree:
...     print(leaf)
... 

--AZ_09099898

--AJIJIUIUZ

--AP_008988

--AP_009008.1_OP_OK-le

--scOK_4174_1944-3504_+__OK_fOK

--sc1_6698-9667_-__Lina_ces

--Iffold_1712_13782-16775_-__Le_a
```

and I would like to add in the list only element that have > 3 "_"

so I should get

```
list=["scOK_4174_1944-3504_+__OK_fOK","sc1_6698-9667_-__Lina_ces","Iffold_1712_13782-16775_-__Le_a"]
```

I tried something like:

```
if > 3 '_' in leaf:
```

Comment: Hint: Use a list comprehension with the `str.count()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)

```py
for leaf in tree:
    if leaf.count('_') > 3:
        print(leaf)
```

Or toss it in a list comprehension (or use `filter`) if you want to use it for more than just printing to console.

```py
filtered_tree = [leaf for leaf in tree if leaf.count('_') > 3]
# or
filtered_tree = filter(lambda leaf: leaf.count('_') > 3, tree)
```